# NUnit: Log test steps and assert description on test failure or error

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

On test failure Nunit will only show evaluated expected and actual conditions. There is no way to tell which Assert failed if you have multiple asserts

```
Expected: True
But was: False
```

Same issue on exceptions: there is a stack trace but its not that descriptive, and does not tell me any details of the steps occurred right before the error.

One way to do it is to pass messages to Assert or add log statements (e.g. using `TestContext.WriteLine`). But this means that every time I write an assert I need to write a unique message or for every step I will have to add a log statement, which is time consuming and will require additional maintenance when updating tests.

Is there an easier way to show this information by including the method call and assert code statements as is?

for example, something like this:

```
Expected: True
But was: False

On: Assert.That(User.HasOrderInvoice, Is.True)

Steps:
   User.LoginToAccount(UserAccData.TestUserAcc)
   User.AddProductToCart(Data.TestProdData)
   User.PurchaseCart()
   User.GoToOrderHistory()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this by using 2 set of libraries:

1. [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) - using AOP I was able to log method calls that represent the steps leading up to assertion
2. [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) - Replacing NUnit assertions with FluentAssertions made assertions failures more readable (https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#subject-identification).

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is to make your tests more explicit. NUnit has a variety of constraints to let you do that - and get much more useful failure messages out.

For example, I would write your above assert as:

```
Assert.That(User, Has.Property(nameof(User.HasOrderInvoice)).True)
```

Which would give a failure message something like:

```
Expected: Has property 'HasOrderInvoice' equal to true
But was: False
```

I find that covers most cases I'm interested in. For any which can't be expressed so explicitly, you can add a description within the `Assert.That()`, as below:

```
Assert.That(User.HasOrderInvoice, Is.True, "Test User Has Order Invoice")
```

Which would give you a message something like:

```
Test User Has Order Invoice
Expected: True
But was: False
```

Comment: it will still requires some amount of maintenance. Plus it does not solve my other problem - How do I log steps leading up to the point of failure. I am looking for a more simplistic approach. I think logging the method call till the point of failure will give me that. But I don't want to include any additional line of code along with my test as it would require maintenance.